# Multiple selenium webdriver instances using Internet Explorer 11 interfere with eachother

Tags: c#, selenium

I have the following situation, I have two test cases running in parallel that each open a selenium webdriver instance for Internet Explorer 11 and both navigate to the same login page and both try to login with a different username/password combo. The problem is that both webdrivers seem to get stuck during username input for some reason.

I should mention that running either test by themselves works without issue, running both tests sequentially is also ok, so the problem only occurs when both tests are ran at the same time.

Also of note is if I try the same thing with two instances of Chrome Driver instead of Internet Explorer, again there is no problem. So this is something related to the IE webdriver and only when there are multiple instances of it at the same time.

Does anyone have any solution/idea that could solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has already been documented [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#multiple-instances-of-internetexplorerdriver) as a known issue, and currently the only way to **reliably** do this using IEDriver is by using separate vms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, even if it wasn't one I particularly like.

Comment: i totally agree :)